# Clickatell Cannot route message to Google Voice

Tags: python, sms, clickatell

When I use clickatell to send sms messages to my google voice account it returns:
ERR: 114, Cannot route message

I am based in USA and sending to a local USA google voice number. So this is not international sms?

Has anyone came across this problem before and if so what was the resolution?
Thanks!

Comment: I get the same result testing with clickatell - might be worth considering, other SMS providers route fine to google voice numbers (I tested with [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com) - where I do some part time developer evangelism).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tip re Nexmo. Will give their solution a spin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got an answer from Clickatell Tier 1 Consultant:

```
"Unfortunately we do not cover Google Voice numbers.

Please refer to the following link, to view which mobile operators we cover:

http://americas.clickatell.com/pricing-coverage/small-business-api/

The reason the error 114 does not appear in the reports is because it fails
on an API level, which means it fails before we can select an upstream supplier
to deliver a text message, therefore an API message I.D is not generated."
```